# How to implement creating multiple resources from a CSV file?

Tags: api-platform.com

### Context

I am trying to implement a custom endpoint in API Platform to create a collection of resources from CSV.

I made a DTO class `EntitiesMultipleRecords` to store CSV records. Each record is an associative array of properties for an entity.
A custom normalizer `EntitiesMultipleRecordsCSVDenormalizer` is required for my use-case. It is setup to alter the output of the built-in Symfony `CsvEncoder` and denormalize into my DTO class.
The DataTransformer `MultipleEntitiesCSVDataTransformer` handles conversion to an array of entities.
Both the DataTransformer and custom deserializer are registered as services, and the denormalizer service is tagged as `symfony.normalizer`.

As a quick test to validate the entire process, I put together this routine which handles it correctly :

```php
$decoder = new Serializer(
    [new EntitiesMultipleRecordsCSVDenormalizer()],
    [new CsvEncoder([CsvEncoder::DELIMITER_KEY => ';'])]
);
$content = file_get_contents(
    "{$kernel->getProjectDir()}/tests/_data/imports/dna/dna_import.csv"
);
$results = $decoder->deserialize($content, EntitiesMultipleRecords::class, 'csv');

$trans = new MultipleEntitiesCSVDataTransformer($em);
$entities = $trans->transform($results, Dna::class);
// got an array of DNA entities
// do some persisting and return response
```

### The problem :

So all the individual pieces work together, but I **cannot figure out a way to configure API platform to use them in the intended way**.

I found [this example](https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform/issues/294#issuecomment-906351019), and tried to reproduce a similar configuration (code samples below).

However, I get the following error when testing the endpoint using the swagger UI :

```
App\\Controller\\API\\ImportCSVAction::__invoke(): 
Argument #1 ($data) must be of type App\\DTO\\EntitiesMultipleRecords, App\\Entity\\Dna given
```

I am obviously missing something here. Changing the type hint of the `__invoke` method parameter to `Dna` does not fix anything, the entity is empty. Moreover if it was possible to work directly with the deserialized entity, an array of `Dna` would be expected, not a single one.

I guess the deserialization pipeline is not even used, even though I setup the resource to use my DTO as input class.

Resource configuration :

```php
 * @ApiResource(
 *     collectionOperations={
 *           "import": {
 *                  "method": "POST",
 *                  "path": "/dnas/import",
 *                  "input": EntitiesMultipleRecords::class,
 *                  "controller": ImportCSVAction::class,
 *                  "input_formats": {"csv": {"text/csv"}},
 *              }
 *     },
 * )
 class Dna { 
     //...
 }
```

This is the action class :

```php
namespace App\Controller\API;
use App\DTO\EntitiesMultipleRecords;
/**
 * @param EntitiesMultipleRecords $data
 */
class ImportCSVAction {
    public function __invoke(EntitiesMultipleRecords $data) {
        dump($data);
        return $data;
    }
}
```

The failing request :

```sh
curl -X 'POST' \
  'https://localhost:8000/api/dnas/import' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: text/csv' \
  -d 'the content of dna_import.csv which is a correctly formed CSV string with ; delimiter'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a [custom data transformer](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/dto/#updating-a-resource-with-a-custom-input) to convert the incoming `EntitiesMultipleRecords` to your `Dna`:

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\DataTransformer;

use ApiPlatform\Core\DataTransformer\DataTransformerInterface;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Serializer\AbstractItemNormalizer;
use App\Entity\Dna;

final class EntitiesMultipleRecordsDataTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
    /**
     * @param object|array $data object on normalize / array on denormalize
     */
    public function supportsTransformation($data, string $to, array $context = []): bool
    {
        if ($data instanceof Dna) {
            return false;
        }

        return is_a($to, Dna::class, true) === $to && ($context['input']['class'] ?? null) === EntitiesMultipleRecords::class;
    }

    /**
     * @param object $object
     *
     * @return object
     */
    public function transform($data, string $to, array $context = [])
    {
        $dna = $context[AbstractItemNormalizer::OBJECT_TO_POPULATE];

        // Add everything from $data (EntitiesMultipleRecords) to $dna (Dna)

        return $dna;
    }
}
```

Then your action can receive the now fully populated `Dna` instance:

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Controller\API;

use App\Entity\Dna;

final class ImportCSVAction
{
    public function __invoke(Dna $data): Dna
    {
        dump($data);
        return $data;
    }
}
```

If you don't need to do anything further with `$data` (which is already ready to be persisted at this point) you can use the `ApiPlatform\Core\Action\PlaceholderAction` instead.